# Streams not supported when using Jedis 3.6.0 in spring boot 2.3.x

Tags: java, redis

Today when I want to using Jedis to consume stream, throw this error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Streams not supported using Jedis!
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.streamCommands(JedisConnection.java:154) ~[spring-data-redis-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultedRedisConnection.xReadGroup(DefaultedRedisConnection.java:591) ~[spring-data-redis-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultStreamOperations$4.inRedis(DefaultStreamOperations.java:310) ~[spring-data-redis-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultStreamOperations$RecordDeserializingRedisCallback.doInRedis(DefaultStreamOperations.java:376) ~[spring-data-redis-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultStreamOperations$RecordDeserializingRedisCallback.doInRedis(DefaultStreamOperations.java:371) ~[spring-data-redis-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:228) ~[spring-data-redis-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:188) ~[spring-data-redis-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:96) ~[spring-data-redis-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultStreamOperations.read(DefaultStreamOperations.java:305) ~[spring-data-redis-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.stream.DefaultStreamMessageListenerContainer.lambda$getReadFunction$3(DefaultStreamMessageListenerContainer.java:236) ~[spring-data-redis-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.stream.StreamPollTask.doLoop(StreamPollTask.java:138) ~[spring-data-redis-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.stream.StreamPollTask.run(StreamPollTask.java:123) ~[spring-data-redis-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
    at misc.config.async.pool.MdcTaskDecorator.lambda$decorate$0(MdcTaskDecorator.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

I have search the docs that I know the Jedis is support Redis stream. Why did this still tell me did not support Redis Stream? This is my dependencies define in Gradle, this code force using 3.6.0 version of Jedis:

```
resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
              
                if (details.requested.group == 'redis.clients') {
                    details.useVersion "3.6.0"
                }
                
            }
        }
```

this code import Jedis:

```
api ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis") {
            exclude group: "io.lettuce", module: "lettuce-core"
            exclude group: "redis.clients", module: "jedis"
        }
        api "redis.clients:jedis:3.6.0"
```

what should I do to avoid this problem? I tried this way to upgrade my spring data version like this:

```
api ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis") {
            exclude group: "io.lettuce", module: "lettuce-core"
            exclude group: "org.springframework.data", module: "spring-data-redis"
        }
        api "org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:2.5.0"
```

seems would cause other compatiable problem. And now I am using `2.3.10.RELEASE` is already the newest version of spring boot 2.3.x. Should I upgrade to 2.4.x? If I upgrade to spring boot 2.4.x, there is no compatiable stable spring cloud version to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using spring-data-redis `2.3.9`.

The support of Streams with Jedis is only available from `2.5.0`. So you'll have to use at least `2.5.0` version of spring-data-redis.

Comment: How to specify the version? now I am doing like this:` api ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis") {
            exclude group: "io.lettuce", module: "lettuce-core"
            exclude group: "org.springframework.data", module: "spring-data-redis"
        }
        api "org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:2.5.0"` but it did not work as expect. @sazzad

Comment: @Dolphin What error did you get? May be you need to add `api "redis.clients:jedis:3.6.0"`?

Comment: I already added this dependencies, I tried to upgrade to 2.4.x, but there is too much compatible problem, It may take me some days of time to upgrade, this way may take too much hard work.@sazzad

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to ugprade your spring version, then tried to upgrade spring-data-redis to version 2.5.0,step 1: do not using the default spring data:

```
api ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis") {
            exclude group: "io.lettuce", module: "lettuce-core"
            exclude group: "org.springframework.data", module: "spring-data-redis"
        }
```

step 2: import the version of jar we wanted:

```
api "org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:2.5.0"
        api "redis.clients:jedis:3.6.0"
```

step 3: force using the new version of jar:

```
 resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'org.springframework.data' && details.requested.name == 'spring-data-redis' ) {
                    
                    details.useVersion("2.5.0")
                }
            }
        }
```